# Sorting datatable columns - data disappears

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a jsp page which I'm using to display a datatable. If I look at the page in Google Chrome it displays fine, but If I click on the header to sort the column. All the data disappears and all I'm left with is the column headers and sorting icons. Sorting works fine in both Internet Explorer and Firefox. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers for reply mate. turns out there's no bug at all. In one of my colums I had  in the code (off screen). Deleted it and all is fine again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem with Chrome/Safari when I had `<h:commandLink />` inside a `<rich:column>` in a `<rich:dataTable>` to open a detailed dataview of a listitem. I changed the `<h:commandLink>` tag to `<a4j:commandLink>` and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine on other browsers, I'd first upgrade to the latest version of richfaces, and if it still fails, I'll issue a bug report ([here](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/RF)), giving enough details to reproduce it (i.e. giving your code, not only explaining it)

Answer (score 1):

Guys check if you are using `<rich:toolTip>` inside the `<rich:column>` for example a tool tip for an image or link inside a column, remove the tooltip and use the `title` attribute of the image or commandLink component.